# Insert a python list into Snowflake as a variant in Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to insert a python list as a variant in snowflake.

Here's what I've tried

```py
python_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cursor = conn.cursor()

insert_query = f"""
        INSERT INTO table (python_list)
        VALUES (%s)
    """
cursor.execute(insert_query, (python_list)
cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

But snowflake assumes I am inserting into 5 column but it should store the whole list into a single  column.

And no. I don't want to store it as a string

Comment: I’m not clear what you are trying to do. “INSERT INTO table” suggests you have a table called “table” - which seems a good way of causing confusion. What appears in the brackets after the table name should be the column name(s) you want to insert into - but you seem to be using the same variable for the column names and the values. What’s the datatype of the column you are actually wanting to insert the data into?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to store the array of 5 elements into a single column. The data type is a variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    INSERT INTO table (python_list)
    VALUES (%s)
```

You will need to do something like

```
    INSERT INTO table (python_list)
    SELECT parse_json($1)
    FROM values (%s)
```

And pass the string `json.dumps(python_list)` instead of `python_list`.

- https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HowTo-Programmatically-insert-the-array-data-using-the-bing-variable-via-python-connector